# Find Child in iFrame?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to achieve this:

I am working on a script that checks a Page for iFrames(done), but than it tries to find the VIDEO Tag of HTML5 in it, store its source, than remove the iframe and replace it by a new VIDEO Tag created with the previously retrieved source, the script shall grab the Element from cross domain Sites like YouTube e.g.

So currently I was able to find all iFrames via getElementB

and btw: JavaScript ONLY

Comment: please put your html code, to be easier to give an answer

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to do it cross domain because JavaScript has the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) that prevents accessing the content from different domains.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned within another answer, this is not possible to do in a cross domain setup.

If this is not an issue, you can access the document of the iframe using the following:

```
var iframeElmnt = documentGetElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var iframeDocument = iframeElmnt.contentWindow.document;
var videoElmnts = iframeDocument.documentGetElementsByTagName('video');
```

You can then hunt through the `videoElmnts` to figure out which one you should insert into the current page.

Comment: Thx for your examples and feedback, i was close to the same result, but it seems my fail was the cross domain issue, so if i try this example, the document content returns a "undefined", now i know why this is...